# Jquery conditions not applied in appended div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/cZDfe/

i have an html and jquery code...
my need is 
1.when press plus button add the same form group items(this is worked)
2.when selected option is "Between" display the second input box.. (in this case only first group s working correctly, and one more problem is there when second group is added, then change the first groups selection, second group is also changed.)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.condition-change').change(function () {
    if ($('select[name="SearchCondition"]').find('option[value="<>"]').prop("selected") == true) {
        $('.second-value').css("display", "block");
    }
  });
     $(document).on('click', '.btn-Add', function () {
        $(document).find('.btn-Add').remove();
        $('#othersearch').append('<div class="form-group"><select class="form-control input-sm"><option value=">=">Greater than or equal to</option><option value="<=">Less than or equal to</option><option value="<>">Between</option></select><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Value"> <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm second-value" placeholder="Value" style="display:none;"><input type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-Add" value="+" /></div></br>'); // end append           
    });
});

  <form class="form-inline">
               <div class="form-group">
               <select class="form-control input-sm condition-change" name="SearchCondition">
                   <option value=">=">Greater than or equal to</option>
                   <option value="<=">Less than or equal to</option>
                   <option value="<>">Between</option>
               </select>
               <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Value">
               <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm second-value" placeholder="Value" style="display:none;">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-Add">+</button>

        </div>
        <div id="othersearch"></div>
   </form>
```

Comment: Can you please provide the HTML used as well, so we can have a little more context to help you solve your problem?

Comment: @BryanMoyles: Edited.. all things in my fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that you don't isolate your groups so that when you change the select for the first group, it displays the inputs for all groups. The second problem you have is that you only bind your change handler to the first select, not to all selects. Probably the easiest way to fix this (though not necessarily the best) is to use `on` instead of `change` and then to update the display of only the input in the changed group: http://jsfiddle.net/cZDfe/2/

Answer (score 1):

**Problems found:**

1. Event delegation missing for select element.
2. Class name `condition-change` not specified in dynamic content.
3. `$(this)` reference not used anywhere in the code.

---

Here is your code,

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).on('change','.condition-change',function () {
        if($(this).val().trim() === "<>") {
           $(this).closest('.form-group').find('.second-value').show();
        }
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.btn-Add', function () {
            $(document).find('.btn-Add').remove();
            $('#othersearch').append('<div class="form-group"><select class="form-control input-sm condition-change"><option value=">=">Greater than or equal to</option><option value="<=">Less than or equal to</option><option value="<>">Between</option></select><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Value"> <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm second-value" placeholder="Value" style="display:none;"><input type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-Add" value="+" /></div></br>'); // end append           
    });
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cZDfe/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bdjnk/Nj95u/1/) for seeing the below in action.

Doing this the right way requires more than just patching up the question code. The goal can be met in an easier fashion.

```
$(function () {
    var between = function() {
        $(this).siblings('input.second-value').toggle($(this).val() == "<>");
    }
    $('#add').click(function() {
        var clone = $('.clone').first().clone();
        $('.clone').last().after(clone);
        $('.clone').last().children('input').val('');
        $('.clone').last().children('input.second-value').hide();
        $('.clone').last().children('select.condition-change').change(between);
    });
    $('.condition-change').change(between);
});
```

To create new form lines, we clone the first div as the new div (to be placed after the last one) and clear the old content. To add the second value field, we check changes and show or hide it as needed.

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group clone">
        <select class="form-control input-sm condition-change" name="SearchCondition">
            <option value=">=">Greater than or equal to</option>
            <option value="<=">Less than or equal to</option>
            <option value="<>">Between</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Value"></input>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm second-value" placeholder="Value"></input>
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="add" class="btn btn-default">+</button>
</form>
```

Of course, now that the HTML has the button outside of the div (which is how it should be), we need to make sure it's positioned correctly with this bit of CSS, where each clone div clears the button / previous div, while the button floats against it.

```
#add { float: left; }
.clone { float: left; clear: left; }
.second-value { display: none; }
```